# Find maximum depth of water, given height,$h=1.8\sin[2\pi{t-4.00\over12.4}]+3.1$

Tags: trigonometry, applications

> At a seaport, the depth of the water $h$ metres at a time $t$ hours during a certain day is given by this formula; $$h=1.8\sin[2\pi{t-4.00\over12.4}]+3.1$$
>   What is the maximum depth of the water? When does it occur?

I know the maximum depth is 4.9 metres but what I don't know is how to solve the second part of the question. Am I supposed to set $h=4.9$?

Comment: How do you know that the maximum depth is 4.9m? What range of values does $\sin(x)$ take?

Comment: I made a mistake when writing the vertical translation.. it is 3.1. To find the max depth I took the center line value of 3.1 and added it to the amplitude to find the max. The answer key I have gives the same result of 4.9 for the maximum depth

Comment: OK, that looks better! Now as to when this maximum height is reached, you are correct; all you need to do is set $h(t) = 4.9$m, and solve the equation for the time(s) $t$. Or alternatively, you could differentiate the function to give $h'(t)$ and set this equal to zero and determine which critical point(s) maximize the function $h(t)$.

Comment: @okrzysik I'm not sure what you mean by setting $h(t)=4.9$, can you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: So you want to know at which time(s), $t$: $h(t) = 4.9$m, so you simply write $4.9 = 1.8 \sin \left[ 2 \pi \left( \frac{t - 4}{12.4} \right) \right] + 3.1$. Now you are interested in the time(s) $t$ that satisfy this equation. So you need to solve this equation for $t$, do you understand how to do this?

Comment: Would I do this? $$4.9=1.8[2\pi({t-4\over 12.4})+3.1$$

Comment: Yes..., this is the equation I've written above. Now you need to solve this for $t$.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to input the rest of the problem. I'm not sure what to do afterwards... $$4.9=1.8sin[2\pi({t-4\over 12.4})]+3.1$$ $$4.9-3.1=1.8sin[2\pi9{t-4\over 12.4})]$$ $${1.8\over 1.8}=sin[2\pi({t-4\over 12.4})]$$ $$1=sin[2\pi({t-4\over 12.4})]$$ $$arcsin(1)=[2\pi({t-4\over 12.4})]$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31627/discussion-between-okrzysik-and-dunja-elez).

Answer (score 1):

Given $h=1.8sin[2\pi{t-4.00\over12.4}]+3.1$

We have to find $\max{h}=\max{1.8sin[2\pi{t-4.00\over12.4}]+3.1}=1.8\max{\sin[2\pi{t-4.00\over12.4}]}+3.1$

And we know $\max{\sin[2\pi{t-4.00\over12.4}]}=1$, hence $\max{h}=1.8+3.1=4.9$

Now, to find time $t$ at which the maximum height occurs, solve for $t$ in $1=sin[2\pi{t-4.00\over12.4}]$, and one of the solutions will be ${\pi\over2}=2\pi{t-4.00\over12.4}\implies t=7.1$